# Anonymous type. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I have seen there are quite a number of references on this error here on SO but I am not able to relate the solutions to fix mine. In my case I am trying to merge two different tables with similar fields.  below is the  controller action

```
public IEnumerable Report(int? year, Guid? gcode)
            {
                DateTime startdate = (new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year - 1, 7, 1));
                DateTime enddate = (new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 6, 30));

                //get all online payments
                var c = from of in db.OnlinePayments.Include(i => i.Customer).ToList()
                        select new { of.Customer, of.CustomerID, of.PDate, of.Pay, of.POK };
                // get all  offline payments
                var b = from pa in db.OfflinePayments.Include(i => i.Customer).ToList()
                        select new { pa.Customer,  pa.CustomerID, pa.PDate, pa.Pay,pa.POK };
                var all = c.Concat(b);

                var query =
                              (from bk in db.Customers.Where(a=>a.Active)
                               join tr in all.Where(x => x.PDate >= startdate && x.PDate <= enddate && x.POK && x.CustomerID!=2)
                               on bk.CustomerID equals tr.CustomerID into trs


                select new CViewModel
                               {

                                   Name = bk.FirstMiddleLastName,
                                   custguid = bk.CustGuid.GetValueOrDefault(),
                                   TotalPaid = (int?)trs.Sum(e => e.Pay) ?? 0
                               });

                return query.AsEnumerable();
            }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What’s the exact error message and on which line does it happen? That being said, why are you calling ToList? This will fetch the entire database table, just to select a few columns which could be done more performant in the database without the ToList? Also I guess this would cause the error if one of your selected properties is not primitive type but an unfetched/non-included entity.

Comment: Thanks  When I removed the ToList() and changed GetValueOrDefault() to Value it is working